# Overriding one property for a hierarchy of classes

Tags: oop, overriding, gosu

I have a hieraarchy of classes. Root class is abstract, and is called Contact, and it has a property DisplayName. On GUI I have a dropdown where various contacts are listed, using their DisplayName property.
I have no acess to source code of those classes.

I want to somehow override Contact.DisplayName property, to make it display something else in my particular scenario. I can not just create subclass of Contact and override property there, because there is whole hierarchy under Contact class. Is there a way to alter a property for whole hierarchy of classes ? Maybe using delegates ?

I am using exotic programming language called Gosu, but the solution based on some common object oriented language could help me a lot too.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but maybe with Enhancements. I'm not sure that it works because DisplayName it's a property of entities.

Update:
There is a folder in Guidewire Studio, configuration/config/Entity Names. Open Contact.en and there is you can customize the DisplayName.

Comment: I have tried that. It happens that in enhancement you can add a new property, but can not override existing one.

Comment: Dragan there is a folder in Guidewire Studio, configuration/config/Entity Names. Open Contact.en and there is you can customize the DisplayName.

Answer (score 0):

Can you type cast the Contact entity to its subtype and try to display it in GUI. Something like (Contact as Person).DisplayName

Comment: I do not deal explicitally with DisplayName call. I just prepare an array of Contacts, and pass it to widget in pcf. Framework does the rest.